# hiding the aView's Navigationbar push bView is OK.but pop Can see the black bars

Tags: ios, hidden, navigationbar

SDK 6.1, Target 6.1, use storyboard

`aView` has a a `UIButton`. I use action segue [push] to the `bView`

When I click this button push `bView` is ok

But I pop `aView` have a back bars, how do I solve this problem?

aView.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

bView.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: show the screenshot. is your black bar animates or stable black bar instead of navigation bar?

Comment: http://d.pr/i/4PBZ no replace,just system controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what is your problem. You are hiding your navigation bar in the `viewWillAppear:` method of `viewA` and you are doing it without animation.

Try this

```
// This will add an animation like slide out. So you may won't like it.
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

If it is not working, then add this code in bView.m

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated]
}
```

Comment: i set [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; to Aview viewWillAppear,set [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];to b viewWillAppear.Have effect, black bar disappeared,thx,but i can see when enter the simulator Aview navigationbar Upward contraction,just 1 second

Comment: Thats great then. But you need to consider my second option too. And you don't have to change this [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]; from your aView. I am saying this because when user enters your app, viewWillAppear shows the animation like slideOut and users won't like it. Anyway good. If my answer helped you, accept my answer.

Comment: i find aView viewWillAppear [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; bView viewWillAppear [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; viewWillDisappear [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; is the effect I wanted,thx

Comment: +1 Thanks for acceptance of answer. That's good. Finally you found what you wanted.